# Segmentation fault bridging CFErrorRef to NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting a crash in the follow code, where the bridge cast from CFErrorRef to NSError is.

> Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

```
    CFErrorRef cfError = NULL;
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef) spam.number, (__bridge CFStringRef) label, &cfError);
    if (cfError != nil)
    {
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"PlaceholderErrorDomain" code:-99999 userInfo: nil];
        error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
        NSLog(@"Error adding phone number to contact. %d %@", error.code, [error.userInfo description]);
    }
```

After ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel() executes the value of cfError is 0x1. Is this supposed to actually be a valid address of an allocated CFErrorRef object?

Any suggestions on the cause/fix of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is that the 4th parameter to `ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel` is not an error. It's for getting back an identifier.

To see if the value was added or not, see if `ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel` returns true or false. But you aren't given any information about why it failed if it does fail.

```
ABMultiValueIdentifier identifier;
if (!ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef) spam.number, (__bridge CFStringRef) label, &identifier) {
    // Unable to add value and label but there is no error to tell you why
}
```